# How to accept root password through shell script

Tags: scripts, sh

Is there any way that I can provide root password in the shell script without explicitly entering it through the terminal

Comment: Could you please explain your final task/goal? What do you exactly want?

Comment: In what shell script? Provide it to what program? `sudo`? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use `expect`.
Install it if you don't have it already with below command

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

and then in a script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#define password 
export pass = "myPass"

spawn ssh root@remotehost 

# detect password prompt
expect "*?assword:*"

# send $password
send -- "$pass\r"

#return 
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```